# Lookup table with 'wildcards' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking for an answer to this problem for a few days, but can't find anything similar in other threads.

I have a lookup table to define classification for some input data. The classification depends on continent, country and city. However, some classes may depend on a subset of these variables, e.g. only continent and country (no city). An example of such lookup table is below. In my example, I'm using one and two stars as wildcards:
 - One Star: I want all cities in France to be classified as France, and 
 - Two Stars: All cities in US, excepting New York and San Francisco as USA - Other.

```
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({'Continent': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'America', 'America', 'America', 'America', 'Africa'], 
                     'Country': ['France', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Argentina', '*'],
                     'City': ['*', '*', '*', 'New York', 'San Francisco', '**', '*', '*'],
                     'Classification': ['France', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'USA - NY', 'USA - SF', 'USA - Other', 'Argentina', 'Africa']})
```

If my dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Continent': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'America ', 'America', 'America', 'Africa'], 
               'Country': ['France', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Egypt'], 
               'City': ['Paris', 'Rome', 'Tokyo', 'San Francisco', 'Houston', 'DC', 'Cairo']})
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
    Continent   Country     City            Classification
0   Europe      France      Paris           France
1   Europe      Italy       Rome            Italy
2   Asia        Japan       Tokyo           Japan
3   America     USA         San Francisco   USA - SF
4   America     USA         Houston         USA - Other
5   America     USA         DC              USA - Other
6   Africa      Egypt       Cairo           Africa
```

I need to start from a lookup table or similar because it's easier to maintain, easier to explain and it's also used by other processes. I can't create a full table, because I would have to consider all possible cities in the world.

Is there any pythonic way of doing this? I thought I could use pd.merge, but I haven't found any examples of this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy-to-maintain way to handle your task is to use maps:

```
df2 = df.copy()

# below will yield a field df2.Classification and save the value when all "Continent", "Country" and "City" match, otherwise np.nan
df2 = df2.merge(lookup_df, how='left', on = ["Continent", "Country", "City"])

# create map1 from lookup_df when City is '*' but Country is not '*'
map1 = lookup_df.loc[lookup_df.City.str.match('^\*+$') & ~lookup_df.Country.str.match('^\*+$')].set_index(['Continent','Country']).Classification.to_dict()
map1
#{('Europe', 'France'): 'France',
# ('Europe', 'Italy'): 'Italy',
# ('Asia', 'Japan'): 'Japan',
# ('America', 'USA'): 'USA - Other',
# ('America', 'Argentina'): 'Argentina'}

# create map2 from lookup_df when both City and Country are '*'
map2 = lookup_df.loc[lookup_df.City.str.match('^\*+$') & lookup_df.Country.str.match('^\*+$')].set_index('Continent').Classification.to_dict()
map2
#{'Africa': 'Africa'}

# create a function to define your logic:
def set_classification(x):
    return x.Classification if x.Classification is not np.nan else \
       map1[(x.Continent, x.Country)] if (x.Continent, x.Country) in map1 else \
       map2[x.Continent] if x.Continent in map2 else \
       np.nan

# apply the above function to each row of the df2
df2["Classification"] = df2.apply(set_classification, axis = 1)
```

**Note:** your original `df.Continent` on the 4th row contains an extra trailing space `'America '` which will fail the above `df2 = df2.merge(...)` line. you will need to fix this data issue though.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed.